# Autowiring a class with an object of same interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have following interface:

```
interface I {
    public String getString();
    public boolean isValid():
}
```

I want to have an implementation which looks something like below.

```
class X implements I {

    @Autowired
    SomeOterClass dependency;

    @Autowired
    I fallbackImpl;

    public String getString() {
        if(dependency.eval()!=null)
           return dependency.result();
        if(fallbackImpl!=null)
           return fallbackImpl.getString();
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to inject different SomeOtherClass object in the fallback.

Is this possible using spring ? If so, any pointers please.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? It should be fine.

Comment: This should work as expected. Did you at least try it?

Comment: I am not clear on how to write spring configuration to inject different  fallbackImpl and dependency using Autowiring.

Comment: You just need to be careful not to have multiple beans that extend that interface.  Otherwise Spring will not know which bean you want for Interface I and will throw exception on launch.

Comment: Ohh that was what I am trying to do.. HAve different implementations for the dependedncy object in fallback and for the dependency object in the wrapper bean

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("nameOfYourBean")
I fallbackImpl;
```